# Bootstrap : complex table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have a specific table to display.
It displays an array of objects.
My object contains:

- common data (displayed in black in the table)
- 'income' specific data (displayed in red in the table)
- 'depense' specific data (displayed in green in the table)

[image]

I did something that looks like what I want but I'm not sure I did it in the clean way.
[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/I4NNCRFb1Ehcy4yPXZGS?p=preview)

```
<table border=1>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th colspan=5>Depense</th>
            <th colspan=5>Income</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan=2> id invoice</th>
            <th>title1</th>
            <th>title2</th>
            <th>title3</th>
            <th>title4</th>
            <th>title5</th>
            <th>title6</th>
            <th>title7</th>
            <th>title8</th>
            <th>title9</th>
            <th>title10</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>depense1</th>
            <th>depense2</th>
            <th>depense3</th>
            <th>depense4</th>
            <th>depense5</th>
            <th>income1</th>
            <th>income2</th>
            <th>income3</th>
            <th>income4</th>
            <th>income5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr >
            <td rowspan=2>id invoice : 10</td>
            <td>10/02/2015</td>
            <td>tartenpion</td>
            <td>II</td>
            <td>AA</td>
            <td>1.25</td>
            <td>FRED</td>
            <td>fact 12</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>xx</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>avoir1</td>
            <td>avoir2</td>
            <td>avoir3</td>
            <td>avoir4</td>
            <td>avoir5</td>
            <td>vente1</td>
            <td>vente2</td>
            <td>vente3</td>
            <td>vente4</td>
            <td>vente5</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Plus : in order to display each record on two rows I had to add a column called "id invoice", then as I don't want it to be display I added some css to hide it.
I am pretty sure my code is dirty, but I don't know how to do that another way.

If someone can help me on this...

Comment: Do you need _invoice id_ in JavaScript? Or why do you hide it? Currently it does not make much sense to have the _id invoice_ in the html at all.

Comment: I don't need it. My problem is that I have two <tr>, this means I have two records in my table here. But actually my need is to display one record on two rows. In real life I will have several records, and each one of them will have to be displayed on two rows.

Comment: Out of your comment it sound like you need it for the visuals, but there I don't see how  that hidden `<td rowspan=2>id invoice : 10</td>` would help you there . Or is it about usability, to help people with screen readers to figure out that those two rows belong together? Or express the semantic that those rows belong together?

Comment: Actually I am using Angularjs, just found a way to do it with ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end. That suits my needs, I can display on record on two rows with these directives.

Comment: `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` and help you with your problem? Now I'm completely lost :D .... but great that you found a solution.